# In jquery animate function is not working

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="E:\Priya\Animation\Horse Animation\js\jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
alert('welcome');
$("#lion").animate({left: '250px'});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div   id="lion" style="width:213px; height:295px; background:yellow;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where the code went wrong. alert is working but animate is not working.

Comment: Do i need to change the jquery library?

Comment: `E:\Priya\Animation\Horse Animation\js\jquery-1.4.2.min.js` Guess you don't have the permission to open that file

Comment: Open your browser console and _look for errors yourself_ instead of being lazy and posting here

Comment: which jquery library i need to insert

Comment: I checked it. It is not showing any errors @Bojangles

Comment: Just copy your library file and place it in a directory same or below where your HTML file is. Secondly position needs to be absolute for an element to animate/move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The element needs to be set with `position:absolute` if you are to use `left`:

```
<div id="lion" style="width:213px; height:295px; background:yellow;position:absolute;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ds5pA/

Comment: I tried with the lion image as follows: <div id="lion"><img src="images/lion.png"/></div>. It didn't worked

Comment: @PriyaSunanthan My +1 for Curt. Since the image is inside a container which is absolute positioned, the solution should work. Anyways it would be easier and more clear to see a fiddle. Can you please share one with your issues properly stated?

Comment: The fiddle is clear to understand even it works for me, but i tried with the image it is not working. Do i need to give the style as absolute for the lion image? @RupamDatta

Comment: @PriyaSunanthan Replicate your issue in jsFiddle, using mine as a start point. Then we can see what has been changed which prevents it from working.

Answer (score 2):

Neither there is a script issue nor a permission issue

Add `Position:absolute;` to your parent `div`, i mean main `div`

The default positioning for all elements is `Position:static`, which means the element is not positioned and occurs where it normally would in the document.

Because `left,top,right,bottom` positioning will work with `position:absolute` so you are missing that one.

Answer (score 1):

Try This
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>`
Instead Of this
`<script type="text/javascript" src="E:\Priya\Animation\Horse Animation\js\jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>`

Maybe your js file not working